# Open Street Map Web Wizard Usage

Tags: openstreetmap, sumo

Why does a pink screen appear when OSM Web Wizard is invoked from SUMO?
I have attached the image below.
[OSM WEB view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvWRD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with loading the OpenStreetMap tiles. We recently had a proposed fix for using https instead of http when loading the tiles. You could try to apply this patch https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/commit/3da7939ea19b246fb845267aa60f0d23ce66908a or simply replace manually in tools/webWizard/script.js

the line

```
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM);
```

with

```
var maplayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap", 
// Official OSM tileset as protocol-independent URLs
[
    'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png',
    'https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png',
    'https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png'
], null);
map.addLayer(maplayer);
```